# DDD - Invariant enforcement using instance methods and a factory method

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern, aggregateroot

I'm designing a system using Domain-Driven design principals.
I have an aggregate named `Album`.
It contains a collection of `Track`s.
`Album` instances are created using a factory method named `create(props)`.
**Rule 1**: An `Album` must contain at least one `Track`.
This rule must be checked upon creation (in `Album.create(props)`).

Also, there must a method named `addTrack(track: Track)` so that a new `Track` can be added after the instance is created. That means `addTrack(track: Track)` must check the rule too.
How can I avoid this logic code duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `Album` makes sure it has at least one `Track` upon instantiation I don't see why `addTrack` would be concerned that rule could ever be violated? Did you perhaps mean `removeTrack`?

In that case you could go for something as simple as the following:

```
class Album {
  constructor(tracks) {
    this._tracks = [];
    this._assertWillHaveOneTrack(tracks.length);
    //add tracks
  }
  
  removeTrack(trackId) {
    this._assertWillHaveOneTrack(-1);
    //remove track
  }
  
  _assertWillHaveOneTrack(change) {
    if (this._tracks.length + change <= 0) throw new Error('Album must have a minimum of one track.');
  }
}
```

Please note that you could also have mutated the state first and checked the rule after which makes things simpler at first glance, but it's usually a bad practice because the model could be left in an invalid state if the exception is handled, unless the model reverts the change, but that gets even more complex.

Also note that if `Track` is an entity, it's probably a better idea not to let the client code create the `Track` to preserve encapsulation, but rather pass a `TrackInfo` value object or something similar.

Comment: I see. About not letting the client code create the tracks, you suggest letting the client code create value objects but not entities like track? Why? Can I create value objects inside the factory too? @plalx

Comment: Also, aggregates like Album, Track, User, etc. usually have all of their properties updated (almost all of them). Should I create an instance method for setting each of these? Or just use a simple setter?  @plalx

Comment: The reason is that if the client can modify `Track` outside the context of `Album` then invariants can't be protected. For instance, if you can't have 2 tracks with the same name the client could violate the rule:

`track1 = new Track('foo'); album = new Album(track1); album.addTrack(new Track('track2')); track1.changeName('track2'); //rule violated`

Comment: Well, DDD tactical patterns may get in the way of CRUD. If you only do CRUD then don't expect to have a very interesting and behavior-oriented model. If the business process is "update"/"change track info", then you could do `album.changeTrackInfo(trackId, newTrackInfo)`. Note that perhaps `Track` is also a value object from the model's perspective if you don't care about the lifecycle of a specific track.

Comment: Got it. I think `Track` is an entity since I'm gonna store data about each track that's listened to by the user. Thanks a lot @plalx. I think I get it now.

Comment: Also note that DDD is all about context. Listening to music & browsing available contents is very different from managing the system's albums & tracks.

Comment: I think my system has quite a few rules. I would appreciate it if you could give me a bit of your time. I have a few questions that are not specifically related to this post. @plalx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222493/discussion-between-plalx-and-amirhosein-al).